# Delete record from database where it doesnot match with physical file entries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, file

I have A table that contains file name and the exact path i.e., XYZ.txt  C:/Test/XYZ.txt
there are few INTEGRITY ISSUES, case: File Name and Location Exists in Database but on physical file location, file doesn't exist.
I there a way, I could write a code in SQL 2008, that checks and delete the file entry from database, if file doesn't exist in provided location.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @file_path  nvarchar(500)
declare @file_exists    int

set @file_path = 'C:\temp.txt'

**exec master.dbo.xp_fileexist
    @file_path,
    @file_exists output**

select @file_exists
Print   'File '+isnull(@file_path,'NULL')+' '+
    case when @file_exists = 1
    then 'exists'
    else 'does not exist' end ;
```

This script checks whether the file exists or not. You can add your logic to delete file entry from database.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code like follows you can find out based on output of the query

```
  declare   @Path varchar(128) ,
    @FileName varchar(128)
    select  @Path = 'C:\' ,
        @FileName = 'myfile.txt'

declare @objFSys int
declare @i int
declare @File varchar(1000)

    select @File = @Path + @FileName
    exec sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @objFSys out
    exec sp_OAMethod @objFSys, 'FileExists', @i out, @File
    if @i = 1
        print 'exists'
    else
        print 'not exists'
    exec sp_OADestroy @objFSys
```

More on the site [Check if file exists](http://www.nigelrivett.net/SQLTsql/CheckIfFileExists.html)